# Laravel Datatable Show Different data from database

Tags: laravel, datatable, yajra-datatable

Hi Guys i wanna ask something

I have column in database mysql like :

```
199910192022032006
```

but when laravel datatable show that data column, its change like:

```
199910192022032000
```

why its can be happen ?

Answer (score 0):

what data type are you using? integer? try to change into float or double or maybe varchar

Comment: i use long integer my brother